# How to check if short code is present in template?

Tags: plugins, shortcode, templates

In a plugin I declared a shortcode, but I want to enqueue the scripts only on those pages which have the shortcode. I tried this:

```
global $post;
if ( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'MyShortCode') ) {
    wp_enqueue_style('style_ui');
    wp_enqueue_script('script_ui');
}
```

It is working fine until I am adding the shortcode inside a template directly.

```
echo do_shortcode( '[MyShortCode]' );
```

I also enqueued scripts inside the shortcode function:

```
public function shortcodeui($atts) {
    wp_enqueue_style('style_ui');
    wp_enqueue_script('script_ui');
    require_once MYPL_PATH. 'templates/public/public.php';
}
```

But its not working for the template.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first block of code is executed when your plugin is launched, the [`has_shortcode`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_shortcode/) function is prescanning the post content to check if the shortcode is present. You then enqueue the scripts. That will work, because plugins are initiated before the scripts are enqueued ([`init` hook comes before `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)).

If you enqueue scripts inside the shortcode, the function will be executed when the post content is assembled. At that point WP is already past the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook. The scripts will then end up in the footer, which may impact their behaviour.

If you use `do_shortcode` directly in a template, your function with `has_shortcode` will do nothing, because it only reacts to stuff that is inside the post content. You will have to replicate the circumstances under which `do_shortcode` will be executed in the template during plugin initialisation to enqueue the scripts.